# Set Shipping Name - Authorize.net PayPal Express API - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, authorize.net

I've got a working Ruby implementation that uses [Authorize.net's PayPal Express API Authorize & Capture function](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#paypal-express-checkout-authorization-and-capture). 
I'm trying to add the shipping method firstName to the request but I always get an error. Here is my code:

```
transaction = Transaction.new("xxxxx","xxxxx")
request = CreateTransactionRequest.new

    payPalType = PayPalType.new()
    payPalType.successUrl = "https://www.example.com"
    payPalType.cancelUrl = "https://www.example.com"

    #standard api call to retrieve response
    paymentType = PaymentType.new()
    paymentType.payPal = payPalType


    request.transactionRequest = TransactionRequestType.new()

    request.transactionRequest.amount = 99.99

    request.transactionRequest.payment = paymentType
    request.transactionRequest.transactionType = TransactionTypeEnum::AuthCaptureTransaction


    #I WANT TO SET THE SHIPPING FIRST NAME HERE:
    request.transactionRequest.shipTo.firstName="Bob"

    response = transaction.create_transaction(request)
```

Here is the error I am getting when I try to set the shipping method name:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `firstName=' for nil:NilClass):
```

I understand the error, but cannot figure out if either I am calling the wrong method on the wrong object or what is going on. The docs aren't very clear on this method call. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used billTo and not shipTo, although I guess they both should accept a CustomerAddressType

so it should be something like:

```
transactionRequest.shipTo = CustomerAddressType.new(
        user[:user_name][:first],
        user[:user_name][:last],
        nil,
        user[:user_address][:street],
        user[:user_address][:city],
        user[:user_address][:state],
        user[:user_address][:zip],
        'USA'
      )
```

I left the fields but you should check if the order is the same for "shipTo".

Comment: This works perfectly for both. This also fixed my duplicate transaction issue. Thanks for the help.